# Sharepoint mechanism to add scripts to aspx page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

(a) Is there a mechanism (by sharepoint) of registering to include a script into the aspx page?

(b) If yes, then if I do the following from a user control what would be the result?

```
Debug.Print(this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("foo"));
```

Assume that `foo` is the name of script-include which I have somehow registed by some sharepoint mechanism [i.e. (a)]

Answer (score 1):

1. You could simply use a `<ScriptLink>` element in your web part [here](http://www.isurinder.com/blog/post/2011/02/03/Reference-Custom-CSS-and-JavaScript-files-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx#.UKpIBoeQNZg).
2. You can create a control and deploy it in a feature so that the script is on all pages and available for you [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx).
3. You could simply add the script to your web part link you would any other javascript.

To add in Hugh Wood's point. The Control Template (2nd option) is the better option.

Comment: A control template is the better two of the options, you don't need the designer gubbins, but it more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try embeding your js into the dll and register it from the oninit.
The downside is that if you need to make a change in your js file, you'll need to redeploy de dll into the gac
[Here's how](http://nekonekopunch.tumblr.com/post/35710175053/embedding-web-resources-style-sheets-javascript-files)